# express $a$ in terms of $b$ and $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $$c=\frac{\sqrt{a+3b}}{a-3b}$$ express $a$ in terms of $b$ and $c$

My attempt,

\begin{align}c^2(a^2-6ab+9b^2)&=a+3b\\
c^2a^2+(-6bc^2-1)a+9b^2c^2-3b&=0\\
a&=\frac{-(-6bc^2-1)\pm \sqrt{(-6bc^2-1)^2-4c^2(9b^2c^2-3b)}}{2c^2}\\
a&=\frac{6bc^2+1\pm \sqrt{24bc^2+1}}{2c^2}\end{align}

My question: Is my answer correct?

Comment: If we are dealing with real numbers then the original expression places an implicit restriction that $a + 3b \geq 0$ which may exclude some results from your answer (I didn't check).  And, of course, $a - 3b \neq 0$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) is a good site for checking answers - in this case, it says [you are correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+c%3D(root(a%2B3b))%2F(a-3b)+for+a)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no answer can be added to this question as OP is only verifying  that whether  answer is correct or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: Not quite. By the positiveness of the square root, $c$ and $a-3b$ must have the same sign. Then as the sign of $c$ does not influence the expression of $a$, not all solutions are acceptable.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: IMO, it is a question and it requires an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, let $d:=a-3b$, and

$$c=\frac{\sqrt{d+6b}}d,$$ giving

$$c^2d^2-d-6b=0,$$

$$d=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24bc^2}}{2c^2}.$$

But to ensure $cd\ge0$, the sign of the numerator must be that of $c$ and

$$d=\begin{cases}c>0\to\begin{cases}-1\le24bc^2<0\to\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24bc^2}}{2c^2}\\24bc^2>0\to\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+24bc^2}}{2c^2}\end{cases}\\c<0\to\begin{cases}-1\le24bc^2<0\to\text{no solution}\\24bc^2>0\to\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+24bc^2}}{2c^2}\end{cases}\end{cases}.$$

When $c=0$, $d=-6b$.

Comment: +0 for good answer, +1 for tremendous use of curly braces.:-)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take on Yves Daoust's approach:

Let $\sqrt{a+3b}=u\ge0$, so that $a=u^2-3b$.  Then

$$c={u\over u^2-6b}\implies cu^2-u-6bc=0$$

The quadratic formula gives

$$u={1\pm\sqrt{1+24bc^2}\over2c}$$

as the formal solutions.  It is convenient to rewrite them as

$$u={1+\sqrt{1+24bc^3}\over2c}\qquad\text{and}\qquad u={-12bc\over1+\sqrt{1+24bc^2}}$$

From this it's easy to see that $u$ has no (real) solutions if $24bc^2\lt-1$, while

$$u=
\begin{cases}
0&\quad\text{if}\quad c=0\\\\
\displaystyle{1+\sqrt{1+24bc^3}\over2c}&\quad\text{if}\quad b,c\gt0\\\\
\displaystyle{1-\sqrt{1+24bc^3}\over2c}&\quad\text{if}\quad c\lt0\le b\\\\
\displaystyle{1\pm\sqrt{1+24bc^3}\over2c}&\quad\text{if}\quad\displaystyle{-1\over24c^2}\le b\lt0\lt c
\end{cases}$$

Note that the final case describes two solutions except when $b={-1\over24c^2}$.